# Decide whether the following sets have the fixed-point property.

Tags: general-topology

My definition for the FPP: A topological space $X$ has the FPP if for every continuous function $f: X \to X,$ there exists an $x_0 \in X$ such that $f(x_0)=x_0.$

Do the $A$ and $B$ have the fixed-point property?

> $ A = \{(x,0):-1 \leqslant x \leqslant 1 \} \cup \{(0,y):0 \leqslant y \leqslant 1 \}$

Suppose $a \in A.$ Then either $a = (x,0)$ where $-1 \leqslant x \leqslant 1$ or $a = (0,y)$ where $0 \leqslant y \leqslant 1.$

> $B = \{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1 \} \cup \{(x,0):1 \leqslant x \leqslant 2 \}$

Suppose $b \in B.$ Then either $b =(x,y)$ where all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ lie on the unit circle centered at $(0,0)$ or $b =(x,0)$ with $1 \leqslant x \leqslant 2.$

I'm having trouble coming up with functions without fixed points here. Is there a function that doesn't have fixed points in these sets? Or do these sets have the FPP?

Comment: Your function $f$ doesn't work, $f(0,0)=(0,0)$.

Comment: For $B$, do you know whether a circle has the FPP?

Comment: Yeah, but B is a circle with a tail glued on.  You can rotate  the points of the  circle but the tail gets ripped, stretched, or sucked up if try.  But I think if the tail gets sucked up is okay. Let f(x,y) = (x,y) rotated 10 degrees if x is in the unit circle and f(x,y) = (x, 0) rotated 10 degrees for for (1<= x <=2,0).  That's continuous with no fixed points I think.

Comment: It's been decades but ... A, which looks like the letter T, is compact, closed, and simply connected (can be shrunk down to a point; or is path connected meaning all paths between two points can be continuously transformed to each other) so will always have a fixed point.  B has a "hole" in it.  It isn't simply connected (shrinking it to a point requires "ripping") so you can find a function without a fixed point.

Comment: For B, let g(1<=x <2,0) = (1,0) and leaves all other points fixed.  This is a continuous map that "sucks" in the tail. g(B) is the unit circle.  Let h:circle to circle.  Let h(x,y) = (sin(arctan(x/y) + v), cos(arctan(x/y) + v).  In other words h rotates the circle by an angle of v.  This is a continuous map with no fixed points.  Let f = h(g()).  This maps B to the unit circle leaving no points fixed.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey My guess is no, would $f(x,y)=(-x,-y)$ be a continuous function without any fixed points for the circle?

Comment: @fleablood your comments are very useful! thank you

Comment: $f(x, y)= (-x, -y)$ has no fixed points. Indeed $f$ is the rotation by $\pi$. @GeorgeDilla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case for $B$ is more or less solved in the comment.

The case for $A$ is harder (if you do not use the general theorem) because it does satisfy the fixed point property. To see this, let $f : A\to A$ be continuous. Let $p = (0,0)$. Note that if $f(A)$ does not contain $p$, then $f(A)$ must stay inside one of the three intervals ($p$ is the common intersection point in $A = "\perp"$, taking away $p$ gives you three connected components). For example if $f(A) \subset I_1 =\{(x, 0): -1\le x\le 0\}$, then 
$$f|_{I_1} :I_1 \to I_1$$
is continuous and has a fixed point (I assumed you know how to show this using intermediate value theorem)

So we assume $p \in f(A)$. If $f(p) = p$, we are done. If not, then $f(p)$ must lie in one of the three intervals. Assume $f(p) \in \{(x, 0) : -1\le x<0\}$. Then by continuity, there is an open set $U$ containing $p$ so that $f(U) \subset \{ (x,0) : -1\le 0 <1\}$. In particular, there is a closed interval 
$$I = \{(x, 0) : x_0 \le x \le 0\}$$
so that $f(I)\subset I_1$. Now if $f(I_1)$ does not contain $p$, then $f(I_1) \subset I_1$ and so has a fixed point. If $f(I_1)$ contains $p$, let $x_0 <0$ so that $f((x_0, 0)) = p$ and $f((x, 0)) \in I_1$ for all $x \in [x_0, 0]$. Write $f((x, 0)) = (h(x), 0)$ for all $x\in [x_0, 0]$. Define

$$g : [x_0, 0] \to \mathbb R$$
by $g(x) = h(x) -x.$ Then $g(x_0) = 0 - x_0 >0$ and $g(0) = h(0) <0$ (as $f(p) \in \{(x,0) :  -1\le x<0 \}$. Thus by the intermediate value theorem again, there is $y\in [x_0, 0]$ so that $g(y) = 0$. That is $y = h(y)$. This implies 
$$f((y, 0)) = (h(y), 0) = (y, 0)$$
and so $(y, 0)$ is a fixed point of $f$.

Remark: One can also prove the fixed point property of $A$ using [Lefschetz's fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem#Formal_statement).

Answer (score 0):

The case for $A$ is in fact fairly simple when you consider it is a retract of $\mathbb{D}^2$. The Brouwer Fixed Point theorem (not exactly trivial but a very standard result) states that $\mathbb{D}^2$ has the FPP. It is not hard to show that any retract of a space with FPP also has the FPP.